# JRDesignExpression setText() syntax

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm using the JasperReports Java API. I'm using JRDesignExpression to show values on a report, with code like this:

```
JRDesignExpression expression = new JRDesignExpression();
expression.setText("$F{" + fieldName + "}");
```

I saw that $F{somename} syntax in some online examples and just copied it, because setText() is not documented, like much of the JasperReports API:
http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/design/JRDesignExpression.html#setText(java.lang.String)

But is there some documentation somewhere else that describes that syntax? I'd like to specify formatting for numbers, for instance.

Comment: You can set pattern via the [JRTextField.setPattern(String)](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRTextField.html#setPattern%28java.lang.String%29) method

Comment: That is certainly useful. Thanks. But I would still like to know what syntax is accepted by setText().

Comment: As I understand you can set any valid expression. You can read about syntax in [JasperReports Ultimate Guide](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/JasperReports-Ultimate-Guide-3.pdf)

Comment: Yes, that PDF mentions the $F{} synax, and some others, in the Reporting Data, Expressions, Syntax section.


It's also mentioned here:
http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/tutorial.html#Expressions


I wish that the API documentation would at least point to the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is correct. I had the same issue, I applied the text and saw *null* value instead. It turned out that the problem was with my code. I compiled the *JasperDesign* to *JasperReport* before I did all the changes. So make sure you do all modifications, and then compile.

```
JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(inputStream);

//perform all modifications

JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);

//continue with export
```

And also make sure you actually add it to some *JRDesignTextField*